# Bottom navigation view not working when i connected it with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to put viewpager in one of the tabs of bottom navigation view, i was successful in putting viewpager but when i click on bottom navigation tabs, they are not working, maybe the viewpager is completely over lapped on the bottom navigation view, i've tried searching but no luck.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OUtZ.png)

The tabs aren't changing when i click on them but when i swipe they are changing and when i click on bottom navigation tabs nothing is happening.

UPDATE : ViewPager is overlapping on all the fragments of bottom navigation view's fragments.

the way i setup bottom navigation view

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                selectedFragment = HomePageFragment.newInstance();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_order:
                selectedFragment = OrdersFragment.newInstance();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                selectedFragment = ProfilePageFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    checkConnection();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Merchants").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("profile");

    profileNotCompleted();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content,
                        new HomePageFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

This is how i am setting my ViewPager

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
    ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MenuCategoryFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Inside one of the fragments of bottom navigation view.

**My question is :**

Why is the ViewPager getting attached to the activity and not inside the home page fragment?

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: So from what i gather you should have an activity where you have setup your bottom navigation and you need to have 3 fragments, ones of those fragments contains a view pager with a tabbed layout. As for your xml the activity should contain just the bottom navigation view with the toolbar and a frame layout in between to load the fragments, the view pager and tab layout should be inside the fragments layout, is this how you have done it so far?

Comment: yes, that how i've done till now @JudeFernandes , but that one layout with view pager is overlapping all of the fragments.

Comment: can you post the xml for your activity layout and the fragment that contains the viewpager and tabs, this seems like a layout issue more than a java issue.

Comment: i re-checked my xml files and i made them in such a way that they overlap on each other, thanks for pointing out :)  now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting up your adapter with bottom navigation view.
You can try [this](https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/)
hope you will get answer.